# Algorithm to find k-th key in a B-tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, b-tree

I'm trying to understand how I should think about getting the k-th key/element in a B-tree. Even if it's steps instead of code, it will still help a lot. Thanks

Edit: To clear up, I'm asking for the k-th smallest key in the B-tree.

Comment: @WeatherVane I believe you might have understood something wrong from my question. I'm asking about the k-th **key** in a **B-tree**. Not a node. (And not a binary tree, in case you misunderstood B-tree)

Comment: That is why I deleted the comment - before you replied. What does this have to do with C?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to write this in C, since I've implemented the B-tree in C. I am not familiar with many languages so if someone proposed a solution in, say, Python, I might not be able to understand the algorithm.

Comment: By the way I just now realized you have deleted your previous comment. Anyway I'm keeping mine there, just in case someone else misunderstands too, so that could clear it out for them.

Comment: By k-th element, you do mean the k-th smallest (or largest) element, right? Not the element with value k or the k-th inserted element?

Comment: @Dukeling Exactly. The k-th smallest element.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok so, after a few sleepless hours I managed to do it, and for anyone who will wonder how, here it goes in pseudocode (k=0 for first element):

```
get_k-th(current, k):

for i = 0 to current.number_of_children_nodes
    int size = size_of_B-tree(current.child[i])
    if(k <= size-1)
        return get_k-th(current.child[i], k)
    else if(k == size && i < current.number_of_children_nodes)
        return current.key[i]
    else if (is_leaf_node(current) && k < current.number_of_children_nodes)
        return node.key[k]
    k = k - size - 1;

return null
```

I know this might look kinda weird, but it's what I came up with and thankfully it works. There might be a way to make this code clearer, and probably more efficient, but I hope it's good enough to help anyone else who might get stuck on the same obstacle as I did.

Answer (score 4):

There's no efficient way to do it using a standard B-tree. Broadly speaking, I see 2 options:

- **Convert the B-tree to an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)** to allow for this operation in O(log n).

  That is, for each node, keep a variable representing the size (number of elements) of the subtree rooted at that node (that node, all its children, all its children's children, etc.).

  Whenever you do an insertion or deletion, you update this variable appropriately. You will only need to update nodes already being visited, so it won't change the complexity of those operations.

  Getting the `k`-th element would involve adding up the sizes of the children until we get to `k`, picking the appropriate child to visit and decreasing `k` appropriately. Pseudo-code:

  ```java
  select(root, k) // initial call for root

  // returns the k'th element of the elements in node
  function select(node, k)
     for i = 0 to t.elementCount
        size = 0
        if node.child[i] != null
           size = node.sizeOfChild[i]
        if k < size // element is in the child subtree
           return select(node.child[i], k)
        else if k == size // element is here
                 && i != t.elementCount // only equal when k == elements in tree, i.e. k is not valid
           return t.element[i]
        else // k > size, element is to the right
           k -= size + 1 // child[i] subtree + t.element[i]
     return null // k > elements in tree
  ```

  Consider `child[i]` to be directly to the left of `element[i]`.

  The pseudo-code for the binary search tree (not B-tree) provided on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) may explain the basic concept here better than the above.

  Note that the size of a node's subtree should be store in its parent (note that I didn't use `node.child[i].size` above). Storing it in the node itself will be much less efficient, as reading nodes is considered a non-trivial or expensive operation for B-tree use cases (nodes must often be read from disk), thus you want to minimise the number of nodes read, even if that would make each node slightly bigger.
- **Do an [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order)** until you've seen `k` elements - this will take O(n).

  Pseudo-code:

  ```java
  select(root, *k) // initial call for root

  // returns the k'th element of the elements in node
  function select(node, *k) // pass k by pointer, allowing global update
     if node == null
        return null
     for i = 0 to t.elementCount
        element = select(node.child[i], k) // check if it's in the child's subtree
        if element != null // element was found
           return element
        if i != t.elementCount // exclude last iteration
           if k == 0 // element is here
              return t.element[i]
           (*k)-- // only decrease k for t.element[i] (i.e. by 1),
                  // k is decreased for node.child[i] in the recursive call 
     return null
  ```

Comment: Can you please explain why the first approach allows a O(logn) time complexity? It seems that we have to iterate through the list of children for the node we are currently considering, so the time complexity should actually be O((logn)^2)?

Comment: thank you, this seems very helpful. Although, I am not sure: is the first one going to work if the `k`-th element is the last one of the B-tree? And that element is in a node that is a child of the root node.

Comment: Since B-trees are used in situations where traversing a pointer to a node is expensive, if you're going to augment it with counts, then you should keep the count for each child with the pointer to the child, not in the child itself.  That also lets you store cumulative counts, so you can find the right child with a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new balanced binary search tree(like Splay or just using std::set) to record what elements are currently in the B-Tree. This will allow every operation to finish in O(logn), and its quite easy to implement(when using std::set) but will double the space cost.