# Find the k-th smallest element recursively in a B-tree with more than one elements in a node

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

Suppose we have the following b-tree

[image: b-tree]

I would like to create an algorithm in order to find the k-th smallest element. I tried to implement what was written in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231825/algorithm-to-find-k-th-key-in-a-b-tree) but I found out that none of the solutions seem to work for this kind of tree.

So far I have done this, which runs fine for the elements of the last branch

```
i <-0
function kthSmallestElement(Node node, int k)
    if(branch[i] != NULL) then
        size<-branch[i].size();
    if(k < size) then
        i++;
        call the function recursively for new branch[i], k
    else if(k > size) then
        k-=size
        i++;
        call the function recursively for new branch[i], k
    else if (k==size) then
        print branch[i]->entry[k-1]
    else
        print brach[i-1]->entry[k-1]
end function
```

I have implemented the algorithm using C

```
#define MAX 4      /* maximum number of keys in node. */
#define MIN 2      /* minimum number of keys in node */

typedef int Key;

typedef struct {
   Key key;
   int value;     /* values can be arbitrary */
} Treeentry;


typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} Boolean;

typedef struct treenode Treenode;

struct treenode {
  int count;     /* denotes how many keys there are in the node */
    /*
        The entries at each node are kept in an array entry 
          and the pointers in an array branch
    */
  Treeentry entry[MAX+1];
  Treenode *branch[MAX+1];
};

int i = 0;
int size = 0;
void FindKthSmallestElement(Treenode *rootNode, int k){
  if(branch[i] != NULL) //since the node has a child
    size = branch[i] ->count;
    if(k < size){
      i++;
      FindKthSmallestElement(branch[i], k);
    }else if(k > size){
      k-=size;
      i++;
      FindKthSmallestElement(branch[i], k);
    }else if (k==size)
      printf ("%d", branch[i]->entry[k-1].key);
    else
      printf ("%d", brach[i-1]->entry[k-1].key);
}
```

Could you please suggest what should I fix in this in order to have a valid output for every kth smallest element? I tend to believe that this problem cannot be solved recursively, since we have more than one entries in each node. Would be wise to make it a heap tree like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846585/k-th-element-in-a-heap-tree)?

Comment: what is the problem with taking a normal b-tree sorting algorithm and taking the kth element?

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve] which demonstrates what you have achieved.

Comment: The posted code is not C but some pseudo code. You say that it "runs fine for the elements of the last branch". Okay - but if you have some C code, post that instead of pseudo code.

Comment: Since the question lacks basic stuff like data structures and code, it'll difficult for anyone to help you. If the data structure is as I imagine it is then it is possible to use recursion but you'll have to go all the way down to the left to start with and then check "return values" as the function calls start returning.

Comment: @Simons0n you have a point, I was just wondering whether I could solve this problem recursively with an algorithm as shown above

Comment: @4386427 I am updating the question

Comment: @VassilisDe yes of course, it has bee a while that I learned this, but I woul even agrue, that most of the algorithms for trees are recursive. Take this for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-sort/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem *can* be solve recursively. All you need is for the function to return 2 things:

1. The k-th smallest key (or a pointer to it) if it has k or more keys.
2. The size of the tree if it has less than k keys.

The recursion occurs by calling the function on every subtree of the (root) node, consecutively, from the left-most to the right-most, and with different (decreasing) parameter k:

- Let the original/current tree be R, starts recursion by calling the function on R's left-most subtree with the same k as R receives.
- If calling the function on a subtree of R successfully returns the k-th smallest key, then that's the answer and return it.
- If calling the function on some subtree T of R couldn't find the k-th smallest key, but instead returns a the size of T, say n (< k), then:

  - If T is the right-most subtree, then R has fewer than k items, returns the size of R (which would have been found by summing the sizes of all its subtrees and the number of keys in R's root).
  - If n == k-1, then the k-th smallest key is the key immediately to the right of T
  - If n < k-1, then recurse on the subtree S immediately to the right of T with argument k-n-1 (i.e., to find the (k-n-1)-th smallest key in S)

Obviously you'd have to take care of the terminal condition where a tree's root has no more subtree. Conceptually it may be more easily handled by allowing a NULL subtree, which contains 0 key.

Comment: In this case, which should be the immediate right subtree of branch[1]? branch[1] or branch[0]? I am testing your solution, but I cannot reach the third smallest element, which is at branch[0]. Maybe I am missing something. If I try to implement your suggestion to my code above, could you make the appropriate corrections?

Comment: @VassilisDe The immediate right subtree of branch[1] is branch[2]. Sorry, my terminology seem to be different than yours. In my algorithm, branch[0] is the "root" of the current tree, with { branch[1], branch[2], branch[3] } being the 3 subtrees that branch[0] has.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively visit every node and add to a list the k smallest elements of the current node. In the end sort it and get the k-th number.

You could also try comparing the 2 list and keeping the k smallest ones each time but i think it's gonna make the code look more complicated and will end up with roughly the same or worse speed but for sure less memory occupied.